# How to parse Multiple json array in android?

Tags: android, json

This may be possible of duplicate question but am struggling with this am getting json array response like this:

```
[{"data":"25"},{"MobID":"88"}]

JsonArray  jsonarray=new JsonArray(serverresponse);
for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){
JsonObject json=new JsonObject(i);
String data=json.getInt("data");
String Mobid=jsong.getInt("MobID");
}
```

}
Is it possible to parse this type of json i haven't found any parsing method for this above method as a beginner am struggling with this you people are here to help beginner like this Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. please take a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: show me your code buddy.. where you stuck?

Comment: Please can you share you exact json string

Comment: JsonArray jsonarray=new JsonArray(string);

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(serverResponse);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    int data = object.getInt("data");
    int mobid = object.getInt("MobID");
    // use them ...
}
```

Hint: the *secret* (sh!) is to read the javadocs!  All of the methods you needed are in the [`JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) javadocs.

Note: I corrected a number of style errors in your code (and some bugs).  Please compare your version and mine to see what I fixed.

Comment: *"i know but still not works"* - If you want more help, you will have to be more specific.